# Generating secondary Uniqie Id's Mongodb

Tags: php, postgresql, mongodb

I have been trying to find a way to generate unique Id's in mongodb. I know that mongodb has _id which is unique based on time which server its beeing added to among other things. The issue I am having is I need simple ID's for things like users. I know that I could have a collection just for keeping track of these id's that I want but I am afried that when mongodb is in a cluster (sharing and failover) that there is a chance that the same number could be generated twice and in that case to things would have the same id in my system.

I was thinking of setting up a PostgreSQL server up just for handling id generation. ALL it would do is insert a new row and return the id of that new row and then once a day it could easily wipe all date other then what the next key it needs to generate. Does anyone have any other suggestions.

Just to let you know i am using PHP.

Comment: Any particular reason that you want small (numeric?) user IDs? Just aesthetics?

Comment: @muistooshort yup its just so it looks nice the reason is that the company I work for is having me build an application that also has an api that other vendors are going to connect with. I mean sure I could start giving out the _id from mongo but its a little long and it is always easier to compare numbers then it is to compare strings.

Answer (score 1):

bson ObjectId's in mongodb will be unique cluster-wide. thus that is safe.

see also Sequence Numbers on the following page; ObjectId is preferred (scales best) : http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs

Comment: and just to clarify, an ObjectId value can be placed in any field, not just _id.

Comment: yeah i knows are unqiue but my issue is i also need them to be smaller for user id's.